# Writing 2D sytem as Hamiltonian sytem using $\nabla$

Tags: dynamical-systems

Suppose we have the system
$$
\begin{cases}
\partial_t f = g\\
\partial_t g = \partial_x^2 f + u(g)
\end{cases}
$$
where $f = f(x,t)$ and $g=g(x,t)$, and $u: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ are all sufficiently smooth. Let $U$ be an antiderivative of $u$, so $U' = u$. Define
$$
K := \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)
$$
and
$$
H(f, g) := \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2} g^2 + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x f)^2 - U(f) dx.
$$
Then we apparently can write this as a Hamiltonian system
$$
\partial_t (f,g)^T = K \nabla_{(f,g)^T} H(f,g).
$$
The following step now confuses me:
\begin{align*}
\nabla_{(f,g)^T} H(f,g) 
&= \nabla_{(f,g)^T} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{2} g^2 + \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x f)^2 - U(f) dx\\
&= \begin{pmatrix} - \partial_x^2 f - u(g)\\
g 
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
I don't understand how this $\nabla_{(f,g)^T}$ acts on this integral; if it is just taking partial derivatives with respect to $f$ and $g$, then why does the integral suddenly disappear? And where does the minus sign in front of $\partial_x^2 f$ come from?

Comment: The minus sign in front of the $\partial_{x}^{2} f$ term is so that multiplying $\nabla_{(f, g)^{T}}H$ by $K$ returns the original system i.e

\begin{align}
K \nabla_{(f, g)^{T}}H &= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} 
- \partial_x^2 f - u(g) \\
g 
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
g \\
\partial_x^2 f + u(g)
\end{pmatrix} \\
&= \begin{pmatrix}
\partial_{t} f \\
\partial_{t} g
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: I know that it works, but I don't know why it works. My question is how $\nabla_{(f,g)^T}$ acts; why do we have $\nabla_{f} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{2}(\partial_x f)^2 dx = -\partial_x^2 f$ for example?

Comment: Because Hamiltons equations applied to your system gives 

\begin{align}
\dot{f} &= g \\
&= \partial_{g} H \\
\dot{g} &= \partial_{x}^{2} f + u(g) \\
&= - \partial_{f} H \\
\end{align}

Notice the negative in front of $\partial_{f} H$. Hence

$$\nabla_{(f, g)^{T}} H(f, g) = (\partial_{f} H, \partial_{g} H)^{T} = (-\partial_{x}^{2} f - u(g), g)^{T}$$

Also, the integral is required to integrate out $x$ so that your Hamiltonian conforms to the ODEs $(\dot{f}, \dot{g})$.